One-dimensional monotone operator is cyclically monotone
I try to understand the proof in the book of Brezis: "Opérateurs Maximaux Monotones" in which it is claimed that a multi-valued monotone operator $T:D(T)\subset\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is automatically cyclically monotone, that is, for every $n\ge2$, $\{(x_{i},y_{i})\}_{i\in\overline{1,n}}\subset\operatorname*{Graph}T$ with $x_{0}=x_{n}$
\begin{aligned}\langle x_{n}- & x_{n-1},y_{n}\rangle+\ldots+\langle x_{2}-x_{1},y_{2}\rangle+\langle x_{1}-x_{n},y_{1}\rangle\\
 & =\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x_{n+1-k}-x_{n-k},y_{n+1-k}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle x_{i}-x_{i-1},y_{i}\rangle\ge0.
\end{aligned}
The main claim made there is that we can assume without loss of generality that we can order the $x_i$'s, nameley, $x_1\le x_2\le\ldots\le x_n$. With that claim the proof is clear. My question is why can we assume that the $x_i$'s are ordered in the definition of cyclical monotonicity?
I will include the proof in the sequel.
Since $x_1\le x_2\le\ldots\le x_n$ we know that $y_1\le y_2\le\ldots\le y_n$ because $T$  is monotone. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle x_{i}-x_{i-1},y_{i}\rangle\ge0=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\langle x_{i}-x_{i-1},y_{i}-y_1\rangle\ge0,
$$
because each term in the sum is a product of non-negative numbers so, it is, non-negative.
